# Cast a struct to a class inherits from the same Interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct, interface, casting

A challenge with a colleague about if there is any way to  cast a struct to a class here the example that we have tried

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IFoo fooS = new FooStruct();
            fooS.Val = 5; 

            FooClass foo =(FooClass) fooS;

        }
    }
    public interface IFoo
    {

        int Val { get; set; }
    }
    public struct FooStruct : IFoo
    {
        public int Val { get; set; }
    }
    public class FooClass : IFoo
    {
        //public FooClass(int val)
        //{

        //}
        private int val;
        public int Val
        {
            get { return val; }
            set { val = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

but we got an invalid cast exception :D
are there  any  tricky way to extract the interface and assign it to  the class  given that an interface is a reference type and a class is a reference type and the class implements the interface

Comment: Casting is validated at compile time and runtime with type checks. The old "magically cast one type to another through an interface" route is well covered, and has little to do with `struct` or `class` types specifically.

Comment: wait  before you close the question  I think it's clear enough

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth did you mean that is impossible to make a casting in this case

Comment: The answer is also quite clear. This isn't possible because unless you have implemented a custom casting operator (which doesn't work with interfaces if memory serves) there is no way to cast from a type to a completely unrelated type. There are plenty of ways to convert, but casting implies involving the type hierarchy.

Comment: Yes. Just like you cannot cast an `int` to a `string` successfully. You might be able to make it *look* like a cast with either an `implicit` or `explicit` casting operator applied to one of those types.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Casting does not imply involvement of the type hierarchy; a `double` and `float` are unrelated on the type hierarchy, but they can be cast to each other.

Comment: @supercat Yes true. In the case of most custom reference types this tends to be the case though.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: The .NET Framework regards identity-preserving upcasts and downcasts as a different kind of operation from the invocation of widening or narrowing conversion operators, but C# uses the same syntax, along with the term "typecast", for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly cast between the two via the interface, it isn't allowed because they are not related to each other directly (ie, inheritance).

The compiler can catch a lot of this type of thing and not even allow the cast to compile. If the compiler cannot do it, the runtime does it. For explicit casting, the runtime will throw an exception on failed casts, for attempts at implicit casting (reference types only) the runtime returns null and does not throw an exception.

The type checking actually checks that `FooStruct` ***is a*** `FooClass`, which it can't be.

However, you can use the casting operators to **convert** between them making it *look* like a cast

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooStruct f = new FooStruct();
        f.Val = 2;

        FooClass f2 = (FooClass)f;

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class FooClass : IFoo
{
    public static explicit operator FooClass(FooStruct f)
    {
        FooClass foo = new FooClass();
        foo.Val = f.Val;
        return foo;
    }

    public int Val { get; set; }
}



struct FooStruct : IFoo
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator FooStruct(FooClass f)
    {
        FooStruct foo = new FooStruct();
        foo.Val = f.Val;
        return foo;
    }
}


// This interface has little use in this scenario.
interface IFoo
{
    int Val { get; set; }
}
```

Don't confuse casting with conversion. Also, be wary of applying interfaces to `struct` types because boxing can occur.

Comment: but here there is no  more needs  for IFoo interface?

Comment: You can use the `IFoo` interface to define the public contract of completely independent types so that they can fulfil that contract. This attempted usage is just wrong for interfaces. They don't let you pretend that two unrelated types can be hacked into each other, but they let you treat those two independent types as an `IFoo` because they both implement it thus meet the contract requirements.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Create a copy method to your `FooClass` that takes instance of `IFoo`, and perform necessary copy there.

Answer (score 1):

The most *hackish* way I could think of (and one you should never, ever use!) is through the use of the `Marshal`:

```
public unsafe static TDest UnsafeCast<TDest, TSrc>(object source)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TSrc))];

    fixed (byte* b = buffer)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(source, new IntPtr(b), true);

    fixed (byte* b = buffer)
        return (TDest) Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(b), typeof (TDest));
}
```

This literally marshals the data kept in `FooClass` to `FooStruct`, which allows it to be "cast" from a reference type to a value type.

You could optionally skip the second marshal if you use the `FooStruct` type rather than a generic type parameter, by casting the buffer to the `FooStruct` type from the buffer directly:

```
fixed (byte* b = buffer)
{
    var s = (FooStruct*) b;
    return *s;
}
```

Requires `unsafe` compiler option, and should *never* **ever** be done in any sort of production environment - it's very slow and unpredictable.

Comment: Never seen it done this way, but it's still a conversion, not a cast.